# Resharper 5.0 and Machine.Specification (Individual Tests are grayed out)

Tags: .net, mspec

I am having an issue with running Machine Specification tests using Resharper 5.0. The individual tests appear as greyed out in the Reshaper Test Runner and I am also not able to debug them using the Resharper. Although none of the tests is running but I still see the green bar as if all the tests were successfully passed. Any ideas as to how I can get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure your Runner DLL and the associated `Machine.Specifications.dll` in the plugin directory matches the version of MSpec referenced by your project file.

When in doubt, just download the latest build from [here](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/project.html?projectId=project27) and replace the files in your `%AppData%\JetBrains\ReSharper\vx.y\Plugins` directory and your project's `lib` or `tools` directory.